# Disable/Enable save button based on the mandatory field being null or empty using Behaviors

Tags: xamarin.forms

I created a behavior 'RequiredValidationBehavior' and applied to one of the entry fields in XAML page. 
It works as, if the entry field is empty, the placeholder color becomes red, thus indicating the mandatory field. This works fine.
The issue I am facing is with the button on the page, where it should to be disabled if this entry field is empty and enabled if the entry field has some value.
I want to achieve this using the behavior I created.

Thanks for the responses in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below code:

```
public void entryTextChanged(object obj, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (entry.Text.Length > 0)
            button.IsEnable= true;
        else
            button.IsEnable = false;
    }
```

And just assign this event to Entry on "TextChanged" Event.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void EntryMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        var keyword = Message.Text;//your entry


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
        {
            OnAddBT.IsEnabled = false;//your button 
        }
        else
        {
            OnAddBT.IsEnabled = true;//your button 
        }
    }
```